# How to map time properties from application.yml?

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I have problem mapping the time added on application.yml

```
bc:
  aop:
    core:
      boot:
        business:
          dailyStartHour: 08:00
          dailyEndHour: 17:00
          lunchStartHour: 12:00
          lunchEndHour: 13:00
```

this is muy java class

```
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bc.aop.core.boot.business")
public class BusinessHourProperties {


    private String dailyStartHour;
    private String dailyEndHour;
    private String lunchStartHour;
    private String lunchEndHour;


}
```

but when I setup the application thrown a parse error

```
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1020' could not be parsed at index 2
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at java.time.LocalTime.parse(LocalTime.java:441) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at java.time.LocalTime.parse(LocalTime.java:426) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
at pnc.aop.core.ofac.boot.BusinessDiscussionDate.discussion(BusinessDiscussionDate.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
```

The think is when I don't use  `BusinessHourProperties` as a configuration like:

```
private String dailyStartHour = "08:00";
private String dailyEndHour = "17:00";
private String lunchStartHour = "12:00";
private String lunchEndHour = "13:00";
```

I don't have problem.

What's happening?

Comment: Just use “08:00” with quotes in the yaml.

Comment: it works @vins, why this happen? (put your answer)

Comment: : is causing issues in the yaml. : is for key value mapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` in your yaml value is causing this issue as yaml uses `:` for the key value mapping. So change your properties in the yaml as shown here.

```
bc:
  aop:
    core:
      boot:
        business:
          dailyStartHour: "08:00"
          dailyEndHour: "17:00"
          lunchStartHour: "12:00"
          lunchEndHour: "13:00"
```